# Xcode - Cannot find storyboard segues in menu options?

Tags: xcode, uistoryboardsegue, xcode4.6

I'm just getting started with programming for iOS on Xcode. I'm currently walking through a tutorial on AVFoundation ([found here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios)). At one point, I'm suppose to make a UIButton link one view to another using a "push" segue. As seen in the tutorial, this segue should be under the "Storyboard Segue" sub-menu of the "Connections Inspector". However, there is no Storyboard Segue sub-menu for me when the UIButton is selected in the storyboard. Any suggestions? Thank you much.

*Additional Information:
I did embed the view with the button in the navigation controller. I'm using Xcode 4.6. The only sub-menu options I see for the button in the Connection Inspector are triggered segues, outlet collections, sent events, referencing outlets, and referencing outlet collections.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Xcode now places the "Storyboard Segues" under the "Triggered Segues". The trigger like "Push" is now a sub-option of "Action". If you drag "Action" to the view you want to "Push" to go to, it will then proceed to give you a drop down of options which includes "Push".